# display 2 instances of same block - performance

Tags: blocks, 7

I need to use the same block on one page on different locations at once. What would be the best option to achieve it, so it would be best for performance? I use context module and I can duplicate block using [multiblock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock) module. Is there any better option or printing 2 instances of the same block perform about the same if printed in template or placed using context. Thank you.

Comment: are your blocks views block ?what is your block type?

Comment: let's assume it is a general cached block